# ReactJS - '@material-ui/icons/Fastfood' not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

ReactJS - '@material-ui/icons/Fastfood' not working.

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import Fastfood from '@material-ui/icons/Fastfood';

class Header extends Component {

render() {  
    return(
        <div>
            <header className="app-header">
                <div className="app-logo">
                    <i class="material-icons">Fastfood</i>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Header;
```

Header.css

```
.app-header {
background-color: #263238;
padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.app-logo{
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.1.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.1.2",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"react": "^16.8.0",
"react-dom": "^16.8.0",
"react-scripts": "^3.0.1"
  },
}
```

The fastfood SVG icon is not showing on the page. The header just shows the text "fastfood" in place of the logo.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the render function as shown below to resolve this issue.

```
render() {  
    return(
        <div>
            <header className="app-header">
                    <Fastfood className='app-logo'/>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: try in this way: <img src={Fastfood} className='app-logo'/>